# How do I write to nested parent in Django Serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django serializers to create an API which I both *read* from and *write* to.

Models:

```
class Biomarker(models.Model):
    low_value_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    high_value_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class BiomarkerReading(models.Model):
    biomarker = models.ForeignKey(Biomarker, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=8, default=0)
```

Serializer:

```
class BiomarkerReadingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BiomarkerReading
        fields = (
            'id', 'test', 'biomarker', 'value'
        )
```

JSON format:

```
{
    "id": 617188,
    "test" 71829, 
    "biomarker": 32,
    "value": 0.001
}
```

The above all works, and I can read and write to it with that JSON format. However I now need to add some fields from the parent model so the *response* looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 617188,
    "test" 71829, 
    "biomarker": {
        "id": 32,
        "low_value_description": "All good",
        "high_value_description": "You will die",
    },
    "value": 0.001
}
```

I have got the *read* part working using these Serializers:

```
class BiomarkerDescriptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Biomarker
        fields = ('id', 'low_value_description', 'high_value_description')

class BiomarkerReadingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    biomarker = BiomarkerDescriptionSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = BiomarkerReading
        fields = (
            'id', 'test', 'biomarker', 'value'
        )
```

However I can't find a way to write to it using the old json format (with `"biomarker": 32` in the JSON).

I thought I would need to do something in `validate` or `create`, but I get a 400 response before it even hits those methods:

```
class BiomarkerReadingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    ... # as above

    def validate(self, data):
        print('validate')  # Doesn't print
        data = super().validate(data)
        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print('create')  # Doesn't print
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

The example in the docs for [writable-nested-serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) and the other examples I've found on SO only discuss the case of creating child records while writing to the parent record serializer, not the other way around.

I do not want to `create` a parent Biomarker via the API, I just need to be able to reference it by `pk/id` in the incoming JSON like before.

I don't mind if I have to change the names of keys to something like this for incoming:

```
{
    "id": 617188,
    "test" 71829, 
    "biomarker_id": 32,
    "value": 0.001
}
```

Or something like this for the response:

```
{
    "id": 617188,
    "test" 71829, 
    "biomarker": 32,
    "descriptions": {
        "low_value_description": "All good",
        "high_value_description": "You will die",
    },
    "value": 0.001
}
```

If that makes it easier.

Answer (score 1):

I hate answering my own question, but the solution was to subclass `serializers.RelatedField`, which is explained in [advanced-serializer-usage)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#advanced-serializer-usage).

This lets you separately control how the value(instance) is represented as serialised, and how the serialised data is used to retrieve or create a value (instance).

```
class BiomarkerDescriptionSerializer(serializers.RelatedField):

    def to_representation(self, value):
        data = {}
        for field in ('id', 'low_value_description', 'high_value_description'):
            data[field] = getattr(value, field)
        return data

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return Biomarker.objects.get(id=data)

    def get_queryset(self, *args):
        pass

class BiomarkerReadingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    biomarker = BiomarkerDescriptionSerializer()
    ...
```

The overridden `get_queryset` is required, even though it does nothing.

This means data going in looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 617188,
    "test" 71829, 
    "biomarker": 32,
    "value": 0.001
}
```

Yet the data going out looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 617188,
    "test" 71829, 
    "biomarker": {
        "id": 32,
        "low_value_description": "All good",
        "high_value_description": "You will die",
    },
    "value": 0.001
}
```

Thank you to those who offered answers, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Using `depth = 1` option will solve your problem.

```py
class BiomarkerReadingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BiomarkerReading
        fields = (
            'id', 'test', 'biomarker', 'value'
        )
        depth = 1
```

Take a look: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization

Comment: Unfortunately the field `test` is a FK, and I do actually need to link it to the parent.